# How to filter English letters in String?

Tags: swift, string, filter

How to filter English letters in String using Swift like this:

`2017-08-23T13:00:00+08:00`

Delete the 'T' in time string:

`2017-08-23 13:00:00 +08:00`

Comment: take a look .. [DateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
func convertDateFormater(_ date: String) -> String
    {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy'T'hh:mm:ss z"
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss z"
        return  dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
    }
```